# How do I set up nginx-debug on Ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: nginx

I'm reading this guide on enabling a debugging log in nginx: https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server. In which directories must I run these commands

```
./configure --with-debug
error_log /path/to/log debug;
configure arguments: --with-debug
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently reading a guide can be interpreted in several ways. Worth to mention here is that not everything written in fixed-width blocks are commands, and the bread text in between those blocks is essential to read, too, in order to know the context. The fixed-width block could represent

- commands (`service nginx stop`)
- partial commands (`./configure --with-debug ...`)
- configuration file content (`error_log /path/to/log debug;`)
- output of a command (`configure arguments: --with-debug ...` from `nginx -V`)
- script (`while $log->writer != ngx_log_memory_writer`) or source code
- something malicious you could copy-paste to your command line with this attitude.

Now that you've learned how to read all manuals, guides and tutorials, everything you need is in the [NGINX debugging log](https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) guide:

> Pre-built [Linux packages](https://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) provide out-of-the-box support for debugging
>   log with the `nginx-debug` binary (1.9.8) which can be run using
>   commands
>
> ```
> service nginx stop
> service nginx-debug start
> ```
>
> and then set the `debug` level. Note that redefining the log without
>   also specifying the debug level will disable the debugging log. In the
>   example below, redefining the log on the server level disables the
>   debugging log for this server:
>
> ```
> error_log /path/to/log debug;
>
> http {
>     server {
>         error_log /path/to/log;
>         ...
> ```

This means that with the packages from NGINX repository (since version 1.9.8) you'd have the `nginx-debug` service, but [`nginx-common` in *trusty*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/nginx-common/filelist) doesn't seem to provide it as it's build to the default binary. All you need to do is to modify your configuration.

Now seek for the [`error_log`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) directives through your configuration (`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`). With syntax `error_log file [level];` you should add (or alter) the level `debug`, the *file* being your path. If there's no level specified, default level `error` gets used.

Answer (score 6):

Nowhere. The `nginx` version provided by Ubuntu already is compiled with the debug option. The steps shown in that guide are meant to be used when compiling your own version of `nginx`, which you definitely should not do if you have to ask the question you asked.

Comment: Where can I find the debug file? Or at least find out where to find it?

Comment: @Username You find it wherever you _specified_ its location to be.

Comment: @Username when you add `error_log /path/to/log debug;` to `nginx` config, you will get debug log at `/path/to/log` file.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/debugging/#debug-log-for-selected-ips

Debug Log for Selected IPs

```
error_log /path/to/log;
...
events {
    debug_connection 192.168.1.1;
    debug_connection 192.168.10.0/24;
}
```